# Удаление строки из большого текстового файла без использования оперативной памяти

Tags: c#, text, .net

Самый быстрый способ удалить первую строку из файла это:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("input.txt").Skip(1);
File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", lines);
```

Однако нужно совершить подобную операцию для файла весом 500МБ, и сделать это из SQL сборки (dll файл) и как следствие есть ограничение на использование оперативной памяти процессом. Есть ли какой другой способ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

да, и он очень простой и наивный.

(я шарп практически не знаю, поэтому пишу алгоритм. Он будет работать практически на любом языке, который умеет работать с файлами)

(алгоритм считает, что строки нумеруются с 1)

```
открыть исходный файл на чтение
открыть временный файл на запись.
счетчик строк = 0
пока (есть строки в исходном файле) (while (not in.eof()))
  прочитать строку
  увеличить счетчик строк на 1
  если счетчик строк равен заданной строке, то пропустить (continue)
  записать прочитанную строку в временный файл.
конец_цикла

закрыть исходный файл
закрыть временный файл
Удалить исходный файл
переместить временный файл на место исходного файла.
```

Этот алгоритм потребляет очень мало памяти (если только строки не очень длинные) и не зависит от размера файла.

Если есть желание, то можно сделать более быстрый алгоритм. Суть в том, что нужно пробежаться по файлу, найти смещение для строки и ее длину. Потом, сместившись на начало строки, подтянуть конец. Это будет сильно быстрее, если нужно удалить строки в конце.

Comment: Можно в качестве временного файла использовать исходный. 


В конце его просто надо усечь на длину удаленной строки.

Очевидная оптимизация -- открываем исходный  файл для модификации после чтения удаляемой строки и позиционируемся на ее начало.


А быстрее всего сделать это через `mmap`. Мапируем файл в память, ищем заданную строку и ее длину, переписываем хвост в нужное место и усекаем файл.

Comment: фокус с временным файлом имеет один огромный плюс. Если в процессе переноса строк произойдет ошибка (а это всегда может случиться), то ничего плохого не будет - файл не потеряется (а для временного файла можно выставить специальный флажок - и система его сама подчистит).

Comment: Безусловно. 

Если требуется, то таким манером (переименовывая файлы) можно делать .bak файлы.

Answer (score 5):

.NET 4.0 и выше?
Считать первую строку из потока, встать на ее длину+длину конца строки, сделать CopyTo с требуемым буфером. Что-нибудь типа:

```
        FileStream fs=new FileStream(inputFileName,FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader sr=new StreamReader(fs);

        FileStream fsnew = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create);
        var ss=sr.ReadLine();

        fs.Seek(ss.Length+rowTerminator.Length,SeekOrigin.Begin);
        fs.CopyTo(fsnew,81920);
```

на текстовом файле в 160мб отработало за 160мс. ReadLines/WriteAllLines - за 1400

Comment: Ну у меня разница была примерно в 1 сек в пользу ReadLines/WriteAllLines, но зато памяти жрёт намного меньше

Comment: Интересный разброс результатов!

Наводит на мысли о правильности измерений (сколько раз запускать и в каком порядке, учитывать ли первый замер, удалять ли каждый раз результат и т.д.).